# Asp.net webforms onclick not firing on qa environments

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sitecore, postback

Have problem on QA environment. When we are clicking on any component that has OnClick event server do not do anything. It just reload page not raising any postback. 
But if you will wait about 50-60 sec after page loaded and click a component you will get an error. “Invalid postback or callback argument.” 
If you will use enableEventValidation=“false”  in webconfig you will not get a error after 50-60 sec. It will raise a postback and method will be called.

All this code is working properly on my local machine and on dev server.

Server method:

```
protected void lbHit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(this.url);
}
```

MarkUp:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbHit" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="lbHit_OnClick" >
 <sdk:PictureFillItem DisableWebEditing="true" runat="server" Field="Image" ID="UIImage2" ImageFormat="picture_box" CssClass="img-responsive" />
    <p >
        <sc:Text runat="server" id="UICaption2" Field="Caption" />
        <span class="gicon chevron-right"></span>
    </p>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I have tried a lot of things to fix it:

- Discover logs, network , console (No errors connected with our
  problem);
- Comparing a configuration of iis and solution (seems to be almost
  same);
- Implement completely new component (same behavior);
- Move solution on new website (same behavior);
- Create new website and new simple solution with only one
  button(working ok);

And a lot of other stuff….

Comment: can you try to delete cache using hostname/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx. I assume your component is cached and your click event is not triggered.

Comment: thanks for reply. cleaning cashe do not helps.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you do not have Sitecore HTML caching enabled for this page or component. HTML caching is not compatible with PostBack.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But cleaning cache do not helps. So I diceded that it is not a problem with a cache. But I will try to disable cache for component and page as soon as I will be able.

Comment: The issue is that the page is cached on first load, so the codebehind never executes on subsequent loads. The only way that a cache clear could be used to test this would be if you loaded the page, cleared the cache, and then clicked the button without reloading.

Comment: After I did clear cashe and withour reloading the page click the button i get  "Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page." Maybe you know how to prevent this and disable this caching. 
Sorry for this questions, I am new in sitecore.